# Filtering objects based on conditions using Ramda

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, ramda.js

I want to filter out below data using **Ramda**. The desired result is to show the properties where `usage === 'Defining'`.

```
const data = 
[{
  "attributes":
  [
    {"usage": "Descriptive"},
    {"usage": "Defining"}
  ]
}]
```

So far this is what i have done and it's not filtering out data and returning the whole object.

```
R.filter(
 R.compose(
     R.any(R.propEq('usage', 'Defining')),
     R.prop('attributes')
  )
)(data)
```

Below is the desired result that i want to acheive:

```
[{
  "attributes":
  [
    {"usage": "Defining"}
  ]
}]
```

Comment: What's wrong with the output you're getting? For me in only keeps objects where one of the properties is equal to "Defining" - is that not what you want?

Comment: @OliverRadini it is returning the complete object this is what i want ```[{"attributes":`[{"usage": "Defining"}]}]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, then [`where`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#where) is very useful when you want to filter based on properties.  But you want to combine this with `map`.  While Ramda does not supply a `filterMap`, it's quite easy to write our own.  We create a function that accepts a filtering function and a mapping function and returns a function which takes an array and maps only those results which pass the filter.  Breaking the problem down that way, we could write something like:

```js
const filterMap = (f, m) => (xs) => 
  chain ((x) => f (x) ? [m (x)] : [], xs)

const definingProps = filterMap (
  where ({attributes: any (propEq ('usage', 'Defining'))}),
  over (lensProp('attributes'), filter (propEq ('usage', 'Defining')))
)

const data = [
  {id: 1, attributes: [{usage: "Descriptive"}, {usage: "Defining"}]},
  {id: 2, attributes: [{usage: "Descriptive"}, {usage: "Something Else"}]},
  {id: 3, attributes: [{usage: "Defining"}, {usage: "Filtering"}]}
]

console .log (definingProps (data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {curry, chain, where, any, propEq, over, lensProp, filter} = R </script>
```

Obviously, there is a reasonable argument to be made for also extracting `propEq ('usage', 'Defining')` into a stand-alone function; that is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do both a map and a filter here, so it's worth having separate functions for each, then composing them together to get what you want:

```js
const data = 
[{
  "attributes":
  [
    {"usage": "Descriptive"},
    {"usage": "Defining"}
  ]
},
{
  "attributes":
  [
    {"usage": "Descriptive"},
    {"usage": "Definingx"}
  ]
}]

const removeObjectsWithoutDefining = filter(
  compose(any(equals('Defining')), map(prop('usage')), prop('attributes'))
);

const adjustProp = curry((f, k, o) => ({
  ...o,
  [k]: f(o[k]),
}));

const mapAttributesToRemoveNonDefining = map(
    adjustProp(
      filter(propEq('usage', 'Defining')),
      'attributes',
    ),
)

const f = compose(mapAttributesToRemoveNonDefining, removeObjectsWithoutDefining);

f(data);
```

[Ramda repl link.](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20data%20%3D%20%0A%5B%7B%0A%20%20%22attributes%22%3A%0A%20%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%22usage%22%3A%20%22Descriptive%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%22usage%22%3A%20%22Defining%22%7D%0A%20%20%5D%0A%7D%2C%0A%7B%0A%20%20%22attributes%22%3A%0A%20%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%22usage%22%3A%20%22Descriptive%22%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%22usage%22%3A%20%22Definingx%22%7D%0A%20%20%5D%0A%7D%5D%0A%0Aconst%20removeObjectsWithoutDefining%20%3D%20filter%28%0A%20%20compose%28any%28equals%28%27Defining%27%29%29%2C%20map%28prop%28%27usage%27%29%29%2C%20prop%28%27attributes%27%29%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20adjustProp%20%3D%20curry%28%28f%2C%20k%2C%20o%29%20%3D%3E%20%28%7B%0A%20%20...o%2C%0A%20%20%5Bk%5D%3A%20f%28o%5Bk%5D%29%2C%0A%7D%29%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20mapAttributesToRemoveNonDefining%20%3D%20map%28%0A%20%20%20%20adjustProp%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20filter%28propEq%28%27usage%27%2C%20%27Defining%27%29%29%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%27attributes%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%29%2C%0A%29%0A%0Aconst%20f%20%3D%20compose%28mapAttributesToRemoveNonDefining%2C%20removeObjectsWithoutDefining%29%3B%0A%0Af%28data%29%3B%0A)